Animation Class update 7.x to 8
I try to update CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Animations to 8.1. I have some kind namespace change problem.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/communitytoolkit.winui.ui.animations.animation?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0
Old code uses: using CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Animations; and RegisterElementForConnectedAnimation.
Question is where all animation stuff is now?
I try to find where is animations now, but i din't find them.
Edit: I found this one: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Windows/wiki/Migration-Guide-from-v7-to-v8
Hope i get this working someday.

This is a temporary issue. Should be fixed with the next .NET SDK.
For now, try the 1st step, if it still doesn't work, try the 2nd and 3rd steps.

Set the target framework to:
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>


Add WindowsSdkPackageVersion in your *.csproj file's PropertyGroup. Make sure that 22621 matches to the TargetFramework but change the last ".0" to ".41".
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        ...
        <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>
        <WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.22621.41</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>
        ...
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>


Update to WinAppSDK to v1.6.240829007 or later.



Did this answer help?
